# Pretty little flower but identity unknown, any ideas?

Tags: perennials

I ordered datura seeds and received 10 seeds in a clear ziplock packet, no label or instructions. I planted 7 undamaged seeds and only 1 came up. It is not a datura, but no one seems to know what it is & last week it surprised me with a tiny delicate flower.[image] the flowers open from pouches and last for only a few hours.
I tried to load a picture of that, but only one shot could be attached.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a plant called Commelina communis, an annual herbaceous perennial. Its common name is Asiatic day lily because its flowers do only last a day. You don't say where you are, but in North America it's considered a noxious weed because it seeds itself prolifically. More information here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commelina_communis

Comment: Figures, they sent another packet that was labeled. I’m in NYS and checked out those seeds, they were labeled an invasive species. I figured the worse seeing that it drops roots in the blink of an eye. Glad I kept it in a pot, I’m going to have to commit planticide 

Comment: Thank you so much, I’ve taken the pics to several landscaping professionals and nursery owners, none could ID it.

Comment: I'm mystified as to why they don't do a search on the internet - that's all I do if I don't know a plant, though admittedly, you do have to put in the right search terms  That's a particularly vivid shade of blue, it seems darker than usual, very nice!

Comment: Why would one kill it if it is in a pot?  Not fair, Bobbie.  Keep it in a pot and remove the flowers as soon as you are able and carefully.  A weed is just a plant trying to survive and found a place we humans don't like.  Even though it is our fault for the top ten awfullest weeds that have traveled around the world only to push out indigenous plants.  In the wilderness. Look up your closest Cooperative Extension Service in your state and talk to them about this plant.  They are the most knowledgeable of all for your locality.